# What is a simple way to have parts of a text field aligned to the right?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, formatting

In my game I display the ammo, in the format **# of bullets inside gun / # of bullets outside gun**, like this:

**10 / 50**

If the ammo in the gun goes below 10 I do not want the text alignment to look like

**9 / 50**

I want the 1st number to be aligned to the right so that the rest of the text, " / 50", does not move. I cannot just align all the text to the right because the 2nd number should be aligned to the left to keep the spacing nice.

I have tried breaking up the text into multiple text fields and using a Text Format's align property on the text field that contains the 1st number to align that number to the right, but that is too much work and I'm looking for a simpler solution. Maybe there is a way to right align just part of the text (the 1st number) with HTML by using the htmlText property on text fields, but any simple solution will be accepted.

Comment: Try using the textfield property `autoSize` and set it to `right`, that is:

`myTextField.autoSize = "right"`

That should keep your alignment.

Comment: Thanks, now I see that my original example for my question (health) does not really show the problem. I realized that with that example, there really is not much of a problem, so I edited the question with the example of ammo. Hopefully that will increase the chance that someone answers this question.

Comment: You can prepend a white space: " 9 / 50"

Comment: One space does not have the same width as a digit.

Comment: Even with your updated comment, `myTextfield.autoSize = "right"` should do exactly as you are describing. I've been testing this locally and it appears correct to me...

Comment: But I only want the 1st number to be aligned to the right. The 2nd number should be aligned to the left. Also, I only want to use 1 text field.

Comment: Is a leading zero an option?

Comment: No, because of reasons I stated above.